# CSS animation animation with delay on subsequent elements

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transitions

I'm trying to animated three dots "falling" onto the screen, in a staggered fashion: every dot appears in the view port with a slight delay. For some reason, the delay is not being applied to the subsequent elements, they all appear at once. Markup:

```
  <div class="ellipsis">
    <span>&#x2B24;</span>
    <span>&#x2B24;</span>
    <span>&#x2B24;</span>
  </div>
```

CSS (nesting courtesy of `postcss`):

```
.ellipsis {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0.33rem 0;
  width: 1rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.23rem;
  animation: fall 1.3s forwards;

  & span {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: var(--step-0);
  }

  & :nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: -0.4s;
  }

  & :nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: -0.7s;
  }
}

@keyframes fall {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-44px);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateY(7px);
  }
}
```

What did I forgot about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animation should be on the `<span>` elements not the `.ellipsis` container:

```css
.ellipsis {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0.33rem 0;
  width: 1rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.23rem;
}

.ellipsis span {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: fall 1.3s forwards;
  transform: translateY(-78px);
  font-size: var(--step-0);
}

.ellipsis span:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 0.7s;
}

.ellipsis span:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 1.4s;
}

@keyframes fall {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-78px);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateY(7px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ellipsis">
  <span>&#x2B24;</span>
  <span>&#x2B24;</span>
  <span>&#x2B24;</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To animate the dots, not the ***container***, you should add `animation: fall 1.3s forwards;` to `span`, not to `.ellipsis`.

Comment: I was just preparing the snippet, you got it faster without snippet, anyway +1!